# fetch photos from facebook album in android

Tags: android, facebook

m trying fetch all photos from perticular album from facebook in android , i am using facebook android sdk to do the task but the problem is , i don't know what url request is required to access the photos inside album ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos`

If it's for a particular person then:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums/`

And then choose the album id and then use the first call

**EDIT**

You will also need to give permission while creating Facebook object in the Permission String array also need to add `user_photos` to be able to load photos

Comment: Well i tried https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums/ , but its returning {  "data": [] } - blank data though i have a album created name "events"

Comment: It depends on the privacy settings of the album/user

Comment: You need the user_photos permission

Comment: @BeRecursive  What do you mean by that, where should that be set??

Answer (score 1):

Code Worked for Me.

I have two function - one is to get Album id and anther one is just retrieving all images from that particular album.

First use `test()` function and then use `downloadpic()`.

```
public void test()
{

    facebook.getAccessToken();

    JSONArray albumss=null;
    String response = null;
    try {
        response = facebook.request("me/albums");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = Util.parseJson(response);
    } catch (FacebookError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray albums = null;
    try {
        albums = json.getJSONArray("data");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i =0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject album = null;
        try {
            album = albums.getJSONObject(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                     
        try {
                       //Here I have selected Profile pic album.
            if (album.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("profile")) {
            //  JSONArray al=null;
                wallAlbumID = album.getString("id");
                       // Now you have album id in wallAlbumID(global varible).
                Log.d("JSON", wallAlbumID);
                break;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now use `downloadpic()`:

```
void downloadpic( )
{


    facebook.getAccessToken();


    String response = null;
    try {
        response = facebook.request(wallAlbumID+"/photos");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = Util.parseJson(response);
    } catch (FacebookError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray photos = null;
    try {
        photos = json.getJSONArray("data");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i =0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject a = null;
        try {
            a = photos.getJSONObject(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    String testing = null;
    try {
        testing = a.getString("source");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
\
    URL value=null;
    try {
        value=new URL(testing);
           //Now you have URL of that particular image use it in your way
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it returns Json : {"data":[]}

Comment: Where did you request user_photos permission?  This is important!

Comment: when u try to login to fb  , like in declaration filed  List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email",
   "user_posts", "user_photos", "user_birthday", " user_friends"); and use it while Login like this   LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,
    permissionNeeds);