# In Android how to add user_photos permission to get the facebook album photos?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook android sdk to access the user's facebook albums and intern get the photos. 
But when I do a `"https://graph.facebook.com/"+wallAlbumID+"/photos?access_token="+facebook.getAccessToken()` it returns blank data. `{ "data": [] }`

I read [in stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706678/fetch-photos-from-facebook-album-in-android) and also [in Graph API for Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) that I need to give `user_photos`permission while creating the facebook object. 
I am not sure how to do so.I read a lot of forums and also checked on SOF but could not find the solution.

This is how I am creating the facebook object

```
facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `ArrayList` of permissions you want to access.  For example, when I did it, when declaring variables.

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = { "user_photos" };
```

Then, when implementing the user login area:

```
if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But I now get the error `{"error":{"message":"Malformed access token AAAEAVpwLuvUBAMeXhXSNPr8TcuUA6DVspgM4ZA9tnJRKfgdvZA6ZAF8g1BZB3xXyzE7MnSh0cA6m1ulO7FgdZCwo9KhbEtc2udXws1wKAmAZDZD?access_token=AAAEAVpwLuvUBAMeXhXSNPr8TcuUA6DVspgM4ZA9tnJRKfgdvZA6ZAF8g1BZB3xXyzE7MnSh0cA6m1ulO7FgdZCwo9KhbEtc2udXws1wKAmAZDZD","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}` while creating the instance of Facebook which APP_ID should we supply?

Comment: @Namratha You should have been given an app ID when you created the app on the Facebook Developer site.  You use that app ID to create the Facebook object.

Comment: @ CreatineDevelopment: Thank you, i did that. But I still continue to get the error. I have posted it as a different question in SOF [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409685/getting-a-malformed-access-token-t-ypeoauthexception-code190). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't see isSessionValid() as a method of Session object...  That was the 2.0 way.  In 3.0 you should do Session.isOpened()

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If you provide updated code, I'll update my answer to reflect accordingly.  Don't know the context as I have not worked with Facebook's 3.0 API.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Facebook SDK 3.0+.  Also, enable the **OAuth client login flow** in the developer settings on the FB site.  Then you can use the following code:

1. First, log the user into FB inside of your app to get a Session object, then request permissions for user_photos if not granted yet:

   ```
   // start Facebook Login
   Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

       // callback when session changes state
       @Override
       public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
           if (session.isOpened()) {
               // check for permission to see user photos
               if (!hasPhotoPermissions())
                   session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(MyActivity.this, "user_photos"));

               else {
                   // photos permission granted, fetch user's albums
                   fetchAlbumsFromFB(session);
               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Here is what **hasPhotoPermissions()** method looks like:

   ```
   private boolean hasPhotoPermissions() {
       Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
       return session.getPermissions().contains("user_photos");
   }
   ```
3. Your app will then present the photos permissions screen to the user for approval.