# Getting a Malformed access token "t ​ype":"OAuthException","code":190

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing an android application to get the Facebook user albums and photos and display in my Android application. 
I have created a **Facebook App with APP_ID 281846961912565**.

While creating the Facebook instance, I am passing this id as follows

```
facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
```

Using this instance, I am able to login to my FB account post on messages on facebook wall programatically. 
After logging in, I get an access_token.

I'm using the access token to get the album ids using `facebook.request("https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token="+facebook.getAccessToken());`

Now I get `{"error":{"message":"Malformed access token ACCESSTOKENACCESSTOKEN?access_token=ACCESSTOKENACCESSTOKEN","t‌​ype":"OAuthException","code":190}}`

Can any of you please help me resolve this issue and point out what i am doing wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "publish_stream","user_photos" };
public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
    Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
    editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
    return editor.commit();
}

public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext()
            .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
    facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
    return facebook.isSessionValid();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook_dialog);
    String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
    if (facebookMessage == null) {
        facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
    }
    messageToPost = facebookMessage;
}
```

R.layout.facebook_dialog is the dialog which pops up asking if a message should be shared on facebook or not. If yes the following method is called.

```
    public void share(View button) {
    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginAndPostToWall();
    } else {
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
}
   public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());
}
   class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        saveCredentials(facebook);
        if (messageToPost != null) {
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
        finish();
    }
}

   public void postToWall(String message) {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);
    parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
    try {
        facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("")
                || response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        } else {
            showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
        }
                    getImagesFromUserAlbum();
        finish();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Later when I do a `private void getImagesFromUserAlbum() {
        facebook.getAccessToken();

```
    JSONArray albumss = null;
    String response = null;
    try {
        response = facebook.request("me/albums");
```

//  `

I get the error 
{"error":{"message":"Malformed access token ACCESSTOKEN?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}

Thanks for your help.

The code above is now the working copy. Thanks to Bartek.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [Errors page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/) in the documentation you will see that when you get `error 190` you should authorise/reauthorise the user.

I suspect that this happened to you because you first logged in, then [added the permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408889/in-android-how-to-add-user-photos-permission-to-get-the-facebook-album-photos) to access the albums to your application BUT did not log out and log back in. Hence, you need to obtain a new access token which will grant the new permissions to your application.

Comment: Also, the Facebook class is deprecated in the newest API. I'd look into updating your logic to work with that.

Comment: @Bartek: Thank you for your response. I logged out and then logged back in. But even then I get the same error. Now my access token is also different. Am I missing something please?

Comment: @Namratha It would be helpful if you posted your code with the question, otherwise I can only speculate.

Comment: @Bartek: I have edited my question to include the code. Thanks a lot for helping me out. Appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Namratha What does your `PERMISSIONS` variable look like? Also, where is your `saveCredentials` function? Did you try `facebook.authorize` with only 3 parameters? (without `Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH`)?

Comment: Bartek:I have modified the code to include the the PERMISSIONS variable and the saveCredentials method. Like you said I tried the  facebook.authorize with 3 args.But now the dialog keeps popping up and doesnt login.Also as @Wenger had suggested that the facebook class is depricated,I started using the new sdk for facebook.With that too I get the error {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Malformed access token ACCESSTOKEN?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN}, isFromCache:false} Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Bartek:With the latest sdk,I'm doing `Request request = new Request(null,
     "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token="
       + session.getAccessToken());
   Response response = Request.executeAndWait(request);` When i browse the (https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN) on the web I get  the correct json. But the response object returns `{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Malformed access token ACCESSTOKEN?format=json}, isFromCache:false}`for same access token

Comment: @Namratha Let's stick to your original code in this question, otherwise it will become too messy. If you want to stick to the new SDK ask a new question. Why do you call `finish()` in your `postToWall()` function before calling `getImagesFromUserAlbum()`? Anyway, your call in `getImagesFromUserAlbum()` is incorrect - you should not include the whole URL or the access token - the request method already takes care of it. Try simply `response = facebook.request("/me/albums")`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Bartek: Thanks a ton. Your suggestion worked for me. Now it is able to browse through the albums and get the images. Thanks again. I will try on the same lines for the new SDK. It will hopefully work. Appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: To help others who would come across this link, I am editing my code so that it works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please check is there &expires in your access token if yes then remove it because it is not part of access_token  and try after that.